# Complex Analysis - Proof that $1-z^{2}$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

You may find it simple but I don t really see how I can prove that :

> > $$f(z) = 1-z^{2}$$

where $f$ is define on : $\mathbb{C} \setminus [- \infty ;-1 ]\cup[1;\infty] $

(Bonus : Can we say that $f(z) \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \left]\infty;0\right] \text{?} ) $

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: It's analytic by definition.

Comment: What definition are you using for "analytic"?

Answer (score 0):

If it's differentiable it's analytic.  The derivative is $-2z$, defined everywhere.

Comment: It s clear now thanks I didn t know

Comment: If it's differentiable in an open set it's analytic. If it's differentiable at an isolated point it's not. The function $z\mapsto |z|^2$ is differentiable at $z=0,$ but would anyone call it analytic? $\qquad$

Comment: With 2 comments you made it clear. If I understood right no it s not , let me tell you why

Comment: $|z|^{2}= z z=2$Re($z$)